# what is the query?

Tags: sql

I have a table like this.

**Table name : message**

```
mid | mfrom | mto | msg
------------------------   
1   |  a    |  b  | hi
2   |  b    |  a  | hello
3   |  a    |  c  | how are you
4   |  c    |  a  | fine
```

suppose i want to show all message of 'a'
i am able to show all rows of 'a' by

```
`$to='a';
$sql = mysql_query("SELECT *
FROM message
WHERE mto = '$to'
OR mfrom = '$to';");
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql))
{
echo $row['msg'];
}`
```

but i want to show only one result if `mfrom` and `mto` or `mto` and `mfrom` is equal. Such as if `mfrom =a` and `mto=b` or `mfrom=b` and `mto=a`. I want to show only one result from them like this

```
mid | mfrom | mto | msg 
-------------------------
2   |  b    |  a  | hello
4   |  c    |  a  | fine
```

please tell me the query.

If there have many (User `a` and user `b`)'s message
will be show only one time

Comment: can you add another example? *if mfrom and mto or mto and mfrom is equal* is a little hard to follow.

Comment: Your question and your example don't seem to be consistent with each other, which make the question confusing. "if mfrom and mto or mto and mfrom is equal" sounds like you're trying to ignore messages from a person to themselves. However "if mfrom =a and mto=b or mfrom=b and mto=a" seem like normal cases, the second of which is actually in your example.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to show two records, then you could do a self join like below:

```
SELECT table2.mfrom, table2.mto
FROM table table1 INNER JOIN table table2
ON (table1.mfrom = table2.mto AND table2.mfrom = table1.mto)
```